# Browser shows redirected url but component not rendered - Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am trying to learn redux saga.

I have an edit page and when the form is submitted, it should be redirected to the dashboard page.

The code is as follows.

```
import { Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";  
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();
render()
    {
        return(
            <Router history={history}> 
                 <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard"  component={Dashboard}/>
               ...
            </Router>
        )
    }
```

The saga for updating user is as follows.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();



function* updateUserDetails(action)
{
    try {
        const response = yield call(userServices.updateUserDetails, action.payload)

        if(response.data && response.data.status === 'success') 
        {
            yield call(redirectToPage, '/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            yield put ({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FAILURE});
        }
    }
}


function redirectToPage(location) {
    history.push('/dashboard');
}
```

**The problem is that Browser shows redirected url but component is not rendered.**

Any idea on how to fix this.

Comment: From first glance, I can't see where you import your Dashboard component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have only one `history` instance. Try to export the `history` object from your first file and import it in the second one to use it instead.

```
import { Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";  
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const history = createHistory();
render()
    {
        return(
            <Router history={history}> 
                 <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard"  component={Dashboard}/>
               ...
            </Router>
        )
    }
```

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {history} from './App.js' //I assumed your first file is App.js



function* updateUserDetails(action)
{
    try {
        const response = yield call(userServices.updateUserDetails, action.payload)

        if(response.data && response.data.status === 'success') 
        {
            yield call(redirectToPage, '/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            yield put ({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FAILURE});
        }
    }
}


function redirectToPage(location) {
    history.push('/dashboard');
}
```